# superfish to use jquery ui theme framework?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, superfish

was wondering if there is a way to make [superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/) using jquery ui theme framework, if that isn't possible right now, what practice can be applied to make superfish using jqueryui styles.

Thanks for your valuable input.

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the jQuery-ui theming API to style a suckerfish-type menu, http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Theming/API ... or use the potato-menu http://labs.makotokw.com/en/jquery/ui_potato_menu

hope that helps a little...

Comment: JKirchartz - thank you! I just quickly looked at potato menu and noticed it relies on jquery ui javascript library, which is ok, however it does seem to be using styling options of ui css. None the less thanks again and i'll see what can be done with superfish.